# Using Yii Model and Criteria on CGridView

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, zii-widgets

I'm trying to use my model with a replacement for the search (custom search function):

```
public function combineCampInputByDate($startDate,$endDate) {

$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select   = 'food.*,SUM(customer) AS customer, SUM(money) AS money';
$criteria->join     = 'JOIN foodType food ON foodtype = food.foodtype ';     
$criteria->condition = "date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'";
$criteria->group        = 'foodtype ';
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

the result will be the attributes for the model + the other table.

i'm trying to display them in the view but it states no such attribute as .... (this is clear since the model doesnt have an attribiute that came from the other table)

So how do i use the widget below on the model result??

frustrates, but counting on the experts :)
Danny

---

Edit:
 1. Controller -

```
public function actionIndex()
{
if (isset($_POST['Filter']) && !empty($_POST['Filter']['date']) ) {
$GetDates = new GetDates();
$this->dates = $GetDates->getDatesFromPostWidget($_POST);
$model = new Campaigns;
}
else 
$model=NULL;
$this->render('index',array(
'model' => $model, 'dates' => $this->dates,
)); 
}
```

Model -

```
public function combineCampInputByDate($startDate,$endDate) {

$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'food.*,SUM(customer) AS customer, SUM(money) AS money';
$criteria->join = 'JOIN foodType food ON foodtype = food.foodtype '; 
$criteria->condition = "date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'";
$criteria->group = 'foodtype ';
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
}
```

View

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'bo-campaigns-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->combineCampInputByDate($dates['startDate'],$dates['endDate']),
'filter'=>$model,  
),
));
}
```

Comment: Didnt get your question. Please add more code for clarifcation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model class create two attributes: `public $customer` and `public $money`.

You can have as many custom attributes as you want, just be consistent with the naming. (You can't use the SQL `fieldname AS something` if you don't have a `something` model attribute first)

EDIT: You should also tell the [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/) which [columns](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/#columns-detail) to display, like this

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
     'id'=>'bo-campaigns-grid',
     'dataProvider'=>$model->combineCampInputByDate($dates['startDate'],$dates['endDate']),
     'filter'=>$model,
     'columns'=>array(
        'customer',
        'money',
       //etc. for more detailed customization, check the links above
     ),    
   ),
));
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didnt work....
what happened is that those values are initiated per object, but when i try to use the widget nothing shows up and the pagination didnt work...if i use the Gii Search() method (default) it does work...i'm missing something!!

Comment: Please be more specific then. What did you expect to happen and what did happen instead? Are you trying to display `customer` and `money` in a CGridView. and they're not showing up?

Comment: yes, that is exactly it...the table in the CGrid is empty and when pressing on the pagination numbers the page just goes blank..
All i want is to create a custom function to replace the default search in the model and then present it as a table using CGrid

Comment: I've edited my answer, please try it and consult the documentation about the [column](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/#columns-detail) parameter of the CGridView as well :)

Comment: still doesnt work... I think i found a work around but it too isnt working, i'll post it as a new question.
Thanks for all the help!!